# Python Extracting Data from JSON without a label?

Tags: python, json, extract, info

The API here: https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=ALL

does not have any labels and I want to extract all of the tBTCUSD, tLTCUSD etc.. Basically everything without numbers. Normally, i would extract this information if they are labeled so i can do something like:

```
data['name']
```

or something like that however this API does not have labels.. how can i get this info with python?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
import requests

j = requests.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=ALL').json()    

mydict = {}

for i in j:
    mydict[i[0]] = i[1:]
```

Or using dictionary comprehension:

```
mydict = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in j}
```

Then access it as:

```
mydict['tZRXETH']
```

Comment: There is no need for `j=json.loads(r.text)`. Just call `.json()` on the response. `r = requests.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=ALL').json()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to Python right now, but it looks like they're organized in a superarray of several subarrays.

You should be able to extract everything (the superarray) as data, and then do a:

```
for array in data:
print array[0]
```

Not sure if this answers your question. Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Even if it doesn't have labels (or, more specifically, if it's not a JSON object) it's still a perfectly legal piece of JSON, since it's just some arrays contained within a parent array.

Assuming you can already get the text from the api, you can load it as a Python object using `json.loads`:

```
import json
data = json.loads(your_data_as_string)
```

Then, since the labels you want to extract are always in the first position of the arrays, you can store them in a list using a list comprehension:

```
labels = [x[0] for x in data]
```

`labels` will be:

```
['tBTCUSD', 'tLTCUSD', 'tLTCBTC', 'tETHUSD', 'tETHBTC', 'tETCBTC', ...]
```